# AzerothCore Docker build cmake error: No rule to make target

Tags: docker, cmake, docker-compose, azerothcore

I'm trying to setup [AzerothCore using Docker](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker#setup), however when I give the command:

```
./bin/acore-docker-build
```

It fails with:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '../src/server/game/Entities/Item/ItemPrototype.h', needed by 'src/server/game/cotire/game_CXX_prefix.hxx.pch'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:936: recipe for target 'src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '../src/server/game/Entities/Item/ItemPrototype.h', needed by 'src/server/scripts/cotire/scripts_CXX_prefix.hxx.pch'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1122: recipe for target 'src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the docker build cache and removing it solved the issue:

```
sudo ./bin/acore-docker-remove-build-cache
```

this command will delete the build cache located at `docker/build/cache`